# Using minimum cover to find maximum matching in bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I was shown an algorithm in a test for using minimum vertex coverage in bipartite graph to find maximum edge matching. It made a lot of sense to me and I failed to come up with an example that proves it wrong, so I'd be happy if you could help me understand its correctness:[image]

Comment: By a "coverage" do you mean a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)?

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Do you know the "max-flow min-cut" theorem?

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes, and I'm aware of how to use it to find maximum matching.

Comment: I deleted the tag "covering-spaces". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) tells us that the number of edges in a maximum matching of a bipartite graph is equal to the number of vertices in a minimum vertex cover.

This immediately highlights one suspicious feature of the algorithm: we are not adding edges to $M$ at the same rate as we are removing vertices from $U$. More precisely:

1. In step 1, we "use up" a single vertex of the vertex cover to add a single edge to the matching.
2. In step 2, we "use up" **two** vertices of the vertex cover to add a single edge to the matching.
3. In step 3, we throw away a vertex in the vertex cover without adding anything to the matching at all.

Therefore if step 2 or step 3 are *ever* used, then the size of $M$ at the end will be less than the size of $U$ at the beginning, and therefore by Kőnig's theorem the matching $M$ will not be optimal.

---

For a specific example, consider the following graph:

```
a  b  c     d  e  f
 \ | / \   / \ | /
  \|/   \ /   \|/
   x     y     z
```

The only minimum vertex cover here is $U = \{x,y,z\}$. One way the algorithm could be conducted using $U$ is to:

- Begin by selecting $x \in U$, $c \notin U$, and applying step 1 of the algorithm, adding $(x,c)$ to the matching and removing $x,c$ from the graph.
- Then, select $z \in U$,  $d\notin U$, and apply step 1 of the algorithm again, adding $(z,d)$ to the matching and removing $z, d$ from the graph.
- Then, we are stuck with nothing to do for $y$; we remove it from the graph using step 3 and stop.

This creates a matching of size $2$, but there are size-$3$ matchings such as $\{(a,x), (c,y), (d,z)\}$, so the algorithm's output is not optimal.